# Replace expressions in a source file from another source file in R

Tags: r, parsing

Hello I have the following problem

Say I have a file `base.R`

```
x <- 1
# comment
y <- Y ~ X1 +
         X2
# comment 2
z <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}
t <- z(x)
```

and another file `override.R`

```
x <- 2
y <- Y ~ X1 + X3
```

my goal would be to create another file `new.R` which is essentially `base.R` overriden by `override.R`

```
x <- 2
# comment
y <- Y ~ X1 + X3
# comment 2
z <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}
t <- z(x)
```

Obviously if all expressions in `base.R` were 1 liners I would be able to use `sed` but unfortunately it's not the case.
Note that I only need it to work for assignations `lhs <- rhs` either if ideally `lhs = rhs` would work as well.

**EDIT: the above is a minimization of my actual problem**

Comment: Is there a reason that consecutive `source`ing of the files won't work? It appears that your `base.R` doesn't do anything with the expressions, it just defines them, so `source("base.R"); source("override.R")` will result in the correct values of your variables.

Comment: Lacking that, it will take you parsing all expressions in `base.R` (perhaps into syntax trees) and looking for specific LHS assignments. If you do it right then comments and blank-spaces (including newlines) won't be a factor, though order of operands might be a problem.

Comment: I would also step back and take a look at how you got into this predicament in the first place. Trying to conditionally replace assignments in script files is a sign that you might want to rethink how you are writing code. If there is logic you want to share, be sure to write functions where you can pass in all necessary parameters. It will make things much easier in the log run.

Comment: Hello, I tried quite hard to reduce my real problem to a minimal one. I'd appreciate you give me the benefit of the doubt that I know I can source both files...

Comment: I understand your point, statquant, and was suggesting it mostly because (a) sometimes the obvious can be overlooked, and (b) your sample code files here would clearly work given sequential `source`ing. For follow-on readers, it might be much clearer if you include an expression in `base.R` that actually _uses_ `x` or `y` that needs to reference the overridden values. But for me, just knowing this (for now) is sufficient.

Comment: Starting with something like `parse(text = readLines("base.R"))` results in a list from which one could parse the LHS of assignment expressions. However, in order to work with this, we'd likely need to update the list and then write that back to a (new) `.R` file, likely lacking comments and perhaps changes to blank-spacing/indentation. Is that a problem? I don't know of a way to read-in and parse the file that preserves the source-file line numbers (that could be use in subsetting/rewriting).

Comment: Edit to add a something that uses x in `base.R`. Simply `parse("base.R")` gives me a list of expressions but annoyingly discards the comments.

Comment: How critical is it to retain comments? It's a lot easier if this is not required ...

Comment: I'd like to, else I think it is fairly easy, just parse both files and match LHS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometime a difficult problem is best made easier by redefining the problem itself.  In the following we suggest a number of approaches some of which have particularly simple implementations.  In (7) we provide code that does what the question asks but you may prefer to change the problem slightly and use simpler code in one of the other solutions we provide.

**1) omit first few lines in base.R & concatenate files** We will assume that override.R should override everything in base.R up to the last statement to be overriden in base.R.  Comments in base.R after the overridden statements will be kept as well any comments in override.R .  Thus in the example `comments 2` will be kept and `comments` will be overridden but could be replicated in `override.R` if desired which seems reasonable since you can't assume that a comment that applies to the assignment in base.R also applies in override.R .

Determine the number of statements `n` in override.R.  Then parse base.R and find the last line number prior to the first line not to be overridden, ix.  Then in the lines ending in that line number find the last non-comment line number, `mx`.  Now write out override.R followed by all but the first `mx` lines of base.R .  In the code below replace stdout() with the desired name of the output file, e.g. `"outfile.R"` .

```
library(utils)

n <- length(parse("override.R"))
g <- getParseData(parse("base.R"))
ix <- g$line1[grep("^0", g$parent)][n + 1] - 1

baseLines <- readLines("base.R")
is_comment <- grepl("^\\s*#", head(baseLines, ix))
mx <- max(which(!is_comment))

overrideLines <- readLines("override.R")
writeLines(c(overrideLines, tail(baseLines, -mx)), stdout())
```

giving:

```
x <- 2
y <- Y ~ X1 + X3
# comment 2
z <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}
t <- z(x)
```

**2) comment out rather thqan omit** One alternative would be to comment out the overridden lines rather than omitting them.  We can readily do that by replacing the `writeLines` statement with the statement below.  This will allow one to see both the comments in base.R, if any, and the comments in override.R .

```
writeLines(c(overrideLines, sub("^", "# ", head(baseLines, mx)), 
  tail(baseLines, -mx)), stdout())
```

giving:

```
x <- 2
y <- Y ~ X1 + X3
# x <- 1
# # comment
# y <- Y ~ X1 +
#          X2
# comment 2
z <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}
t <- z(x)
```

**3) separator** If you control base.R then a simpler approach is to mark the end of the portion to be overriden.  Suppose we put #--- on a line by itself in base.R between the portion to override and the rest.  Then we have the following which is simpler:

```
overrideLines <- readLines("override.R")
baseLines <- readLines("base.R")
ix <- grep("#---", baseLines)[1]
writeLines(c(overrideLines, tail(baseLines, -ix)), stdout())
```

**4) exists** or possibly, in base.R, check if `x` has already been defined and only define it if not.  Ditto for `y`.  Then it is just a matter of concatenating the two files or sourcing one after the other.

```
if (!exists("x")) x <- ...whatever...
if (!exists("y")) y <- ...whatever...
```

**5) function** Yet another possibility is to define a function whose defaults are the current values of x and y in base.R.  Then we can call it as f() to get the defaults or specify them.

```
f <- function(x = ..., y = ...) {  ...base.R code except  x and y ...}
```

**6) Omit definitions from base.R**  Perhaps the simplest alternative is just to omit the definitions from base.R and for each run have a override.R that is sourced first or concatenated.

**7) Keep base.R comments** This one does what the question asked but  it is a bit complex and you may prefer one of the other solutions.

```
library(codetools)
library(utils)

baseLines <- readLines("base.R")
overrideLines <- readLines("override.R")

p_o <- parse("override.R")
g_o <- getParseData(p_o)
locals_o <- findLocalsList(p_o)
ipos <- sapply(locals_o, function(x) which(g_o$text == x)[1]-1)
DFo <- cbind(g_o[ipos, ], var = names(ipos))

p_b <- parse("base.R")
g_b <- getParseData(p_b)
ipos <- sapply(locals_o, function(x) which(g_b$text == x)[1]-1)
DFb <- data.frame(g_b[ipos, ], var = names(ipos), row.names = NULL)
o <- order(-DFb$line1)
DFb <- DFb[o, ]

newLines <- baseLines
for(i in 1:nrow(DFb)) {
  j <- match(DFb$var[i], DFo$var)
  newLines <- append(newLines, 
    overrideLines[DFo$line1[j]:DFo$line2[j]], DFb$line2[i])
  newLines <- newLines[-(DFb$line1[i]:DFb$line2[i])]
}

writeLines(newLines, stdout())
```

giving:

```
x <- 2
# comment
y <- Y ~ X1 + X3
# comment 2
z <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}
t <- z(x)
```

Comment: Nice! My unfamiliarity with `codetools` is a key takeaway, thanks for this; it seems much of my churn (in the portion I didn't post in my answer) is resolved by some of those functions.

Comment: Great answer -> +100
Just note that for some "new" commands in override.R `overrideLines[DFo$line1[j]:DFo$line2[j]], DFb$line2[i])` would need to be amended

Answer (score 3):

If you can accept comments being stripped, then this might suffice for you:

Starting with **`base.R`**:

```
x <- 1
# comment
y <- Y ~ X1 +
         X2
# comment 2
z <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}
t <- z(x)
```

and **`override.R`**:

```r
x <- 2
y <- Y ~ X1 + X3
```

We can run:

```r
base <- parse("base.R")
override <- parse("override.R")

base_assignment <-
  sapply(base, function(z) as.character(z[[1]]) %in% c("<-", "="))
base_lhs <- mapply(function(assigned, z) as.character(z[[2]]),
                   base_assignment, base)

override_assignment <-
  sapply(override, function(z) as.character(z[[1]]) %in% c("<-", "="))
override_lhs <- mapply(function(assigned, z) as.character(z[[2]]),
                       override_assignment, override)

matches <- match(base_lhs, override_lhs)
base[which(!is.na(matches))] <- override[na.omit(matches)]

writeLines(paste(do.call(c, lapply(base, deparse)), collapse = "\n"), "new.R")
```

and now we have **`new.R`** with

```r
x <- 2
y <- Y ~ X1 + X3
z <- function(x) {
    x + 1
}
t <- z(x)
```

---

For conversation, in order to retain comments we'd likely need to use `getParseData`:

1. iterate over `$parent` and `$id` so that our `$line1` references can be combined, store this reduced `line1` into a new variable (since we'll need to remove the originals from `getParseData(base)`;
2. find all references to `$token == "SYMBOL"` where there exists `$token == "LEFT_ASSIGN"` later in each expression. This starts to hobble it a little in the instance we have `"EQ_ASSIGN"` or, more of a challege, `"RIGHT_ASSIGN"` (since the presumed order of symbols changes);
3. step 2 helps us find object names to which assignments occur, which we use to compare between `base`/`override` processing;
4. replace the subset of each versions' parsed frame;
5. find a way to recombine the resulting parsed frame into a source file.

I ran out of time trying to get this to work elegantly/robustly, so I offer it as an example of effort-required in order to retain comments.

I suggest that if your intent is to allow a single source file of overriding expressions, it makes sense to keep the `base.R` untouched (as in your question) and create a *temporary* `new.R` that is used and sourced and discarded, in which case its comments are tangential.

Comment: You can just use `parse("base.R")` rather than `parse(text = readLines("base.R"))`. It seems that even if you did use getParseData to keep comments, you'd have to worry about scope as well which would be messy, like if a function used `x<-` in its body.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick, that was the result of multiple test branches before I came to this partial-fix. I agree that there are issues when using `getParseData`, which is why I started down the path and gave up on it. (Now if I were _paid_ for this, perhaps I'd spend more time on it ... a common plight for SO answerers :-)

Answer (score 0):

This would be very challenging with `sed`, but you could try using `awk`; this works with the example data:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="<-|="} NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next}; {if($1 in a){c=1} else if (/[#<=]/){c++}; if(c == 1){print a[$1]} else {print $0}}' override.R base.R
x <- 2
# comment
y <- Y ~ X1 + X3

# comment 2
z <- function(x) {
  x + 1
}
t <- z(x)
```

Basically, if the LHS from override.R is found in base.R the 'counter' is set to 1, then if any of the "#<=" characters are encountered in the following lines the counter is incremented. Then all lines in base.R with counter == 1 are replaced with the corresponding line from override.R. I can't think of cases where this would fail, but I'd be interested to see if it holds up on more complicated examples.

---

Formatted with further explanation:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="<-|="}          # set the field separator to either "<-" or "="
     NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0; next}   # load override.R into an array, key = 1st field (i.e. the LHS)
     {
         if($1 in a){c=1}      # if the LHS from override.R is found, set "c" (counter) to 1
         else if(/[#<=]/){c++} # if the line contains "#", "<" or "=", increment counter
         if(c==1){print a[$1]} # if c equals 1 (i.e. the LHS is present) print the override.R line
         else {print $0}       # else print the base.R line
}' override.R base.R
```